# How to change buttons (back,fore,icon) colors by using separate class file?

Tags: c#, function, winforms, class, colors

i have 23 iconbuttons(fontawesome.sharp), i want change the colors of that buttons by using that class file please help me with this.

```
 private void Changecolors()
        {
            Button clickedButton = (System.Windows.Forms.Button);
            clickedButton.BackColor = Color.Black;
            clickedButton.ForeColor = Color.White;
            
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button && c != clickedButton)
                {
                    c.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 30, 54);
                    c.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 126, 249);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: where does ´sender´ come from (line 3)?

Comment: i have wrote this function in the (mainform.cs) file. but i want to write this function on the (class.cs). but i don't know how to write this func on that and call it for mainform.